# Servlet 3.0 or Glassfish issue? Web-app ignores asyncSupported for filter when in annotation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I added a filter to my web-app (which already supports asynchronous operations), and forgot to insert the proper annotation on the filter to to preserve asynchronous support. Easy problem to solve. I put the following the annotation in the filter class, which ends up looking like this:

```
@WebFilter(asyncSupported=true)
public class MainFilter implements Filter
{

   ...

}
```

However, after redeploying, asynchronous operations remained unsupported, giving me this error:

> Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not
>   support asynchronous operations

I was able to rectify the problem by removing the annotation, and placing its equivalent in web.xml:

> ```
> <filter>
>     <filter-name>MainFilter</filter-name>
>     <filter-class>com.MyWebApp.Filters.MainFilter</filter-class>
>     <async-supported>true</async-supported>
> </filter>
> ```

What I'm confused about is the fact that the container seems to respect the asyncSupported annotation in servlet files, but does not for filters. Is there a specific reason why, or is this a GlassFish 3.0 bug?

Comment: Are the servlets registered using `web.xml` or `@WebServlet`?

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall: They're registered in web.xml. Are you implying that filter setup has to be dealt with in a homogenous fashion (either all annotations or all in web.xml) in order for them to function properly?

Comment: That's what I would assume without having dug through the specification. Can you try to add `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to your servlet definition and see if that fixes the issue?